# Which LINQ statements force Entity Framework to return from the DB?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I know of several LINQ statements that will cause EF to evaluate and return results form the DB to memory.  `.ToList()` is one.  Does anyone have a comprehensive list of the statements that do this?

Not sure of...

```
.SingleOrDefault()
.Union()
```

**EDIT:** Wish I could accept all these answers.  Great info from everyone!

Comment: `First()`,`FirstOrDefault()`,`Last()`,`LastOrDefault()`, etc

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's a long [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx).  They boil down to

```
Aggregate
All<TSource>
Any
Average
Contains
Count
ElementAt<TSource>
ElementAtOrDefault<TSource>
Empty<TResult>
First
FirstOrDefault
Last
LastOrDefault
LongCount
Max
Min
SequenceEqual
Single
SingleOrDefault
Sum
ToArray<TSource>
ToDictionary
ToList<TSource>
ToLookup
```

The rest are either Deferred Streaming Execution or Deferred Non-Streaming Execution.

In light of your question, `SingleOrDefault()` is Immediate Execution and `Union()` is Deferred Streaming Execution.

Comment: Aggregate?! Wow, that one really surprised me. Did not expect Aggregate to be doing that.

Answer (score 13):

Anything that returns a concrete object or data structure (`Count`, `Sum` `Single`, `First`, `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc.) is evaluated immediately, so `SingleOrDefault` certainly does.

Anything that returns an `IQueryable<T>` (`Select`, `GroupBy`, `Take`) will be deferred (so that operations can be chained), so `Queryable.Union` will be deferred.

Anything that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` will *also* be deferred, but subsequent queries will be done in Linq-to-objects, so subsequent operations won't be translated to SQL.  (`Empty` is an exception since there's not really anything to defer - it just returns an empty collection)

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx),

> Queries that perform aggregation functions over a range of source
>   elements must first iterate over those elements.
>
> Examples of such queries are *Count*, *Max*, *Average*, and *First*. These execute without an explicit foreach statement because the query itself must use foreach in order to return a result.
>
> Note also that these types of queries return a single value, not an **IEnumerable** collection.
>
> To force immediate execution of any query and cache its results, you
>   can call the **ToList<TSource>** or **ToArray<TSource>** methods.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Entity Framework, there's an easy way to refresh your memory.

Entity Framework has `Async` variants of all such methods defined in `System.Data.Entity`, because `Async` doesn't make sense with the others as it's the very act of querying the database that the `Async` variants do asynchronously.

So if there's an `Async` variant, then it hits the database and otherwise it does not.

Enumerating or producing an `IEnumerable<T>` is a part-way case though: The act of obtaining an `IEnumerable<T>` obtaining its enumerator (as happens at the start of `foreach` blocks) does not hit the database, but the first `MoveNext()` (which happens immediately within the `foreach` does hit the database, and it then continues to stream from the resultset until either `MoveNext()` returns false (as when the `foreach` reaches a "natural" end) or the enumerator is disposed prior to that (as when the `foreach` is aborted).