# Why use .ToList after .Include in Eager Loading

Tags: entity-framework, linq, eager-loading

This might be easy, but I was wondering why whenever using the process of eagerly loading that `.ToList()` has to be used after `.Include()`?

I know that eagerly loading allows for the loading of related entities along with the main entity for query purposes, but why does `.ToList()` have to be used?

Is it for a memory purpose or something?

For [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Load all blogs and related posts 
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                      .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                      .ToList(); // why is this needed?
}
```

Any explanation/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624700/which-linq-statements-force-entity-framework-to-return-from-the-db

Comment: I also propose to check that link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx It explains deferred/immediate query execution.

Comment: Who told you that you *have* to use ToList when you use Include? It's not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is during the `ToList()` call when the query will actually be immediately executed. So, your previous `Include` will setup the projection before hitting the database

Comment: okay, your answer along with the link that raderick posted in the comments, definitely helped.  thank you.