# Using IQueryable<T> with LINQ join tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

I have a method of type `IQueryable<T>` and here is it's implementation:

```
 public IQueryable<T> Get()
 {
     return db.Set<T>();
 }
```

I must write LINQ query where I want to join two tables (left join). It is Identtiy table Users and my custom table PersonalInformation which extend User registration fields and now I want to call this method in my LINQ query and it is good. Here is my Linq:

```
IRepository<PersonalInformation> personRepository;
IRepository<ApplicationUser> usersRepository;
var query = personRepository.Get();
var test = usersRepository.Get()
                          .GroupJoin(query,
                                     n => n.Id,
                                     m => m.UserId,
                                     (n, ms) => new { n, ms = ms.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                          .SelectMany(z => z.ms.Select(m => new PersonalInfoModel
                          {
                              Name = m.Name,
                              LastName = m.LastName,
                              Email = z.n.Email
                          }));
```

But I have an error in 
`var test =  usersRepository.Get()` - `System.NotSupportedException`. So  method Get  from personRepository called good but usersRepository  method return null. Where I did the mistake?? Thanks

Comment: Is `Get` a member of `IRepository`?

Comment: @NetMage yes it is interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
 and there is IQueryable<T> Get(); I have an different context error in linq

Comment: So it possible that the real type of `usersRepository` does not implement the `Get` operation of `IRepository`. While I don't like it, some classes partially implement interfaces. What is the real type of `personRepository` and `usersRepository`?

Comment: @NetMage sorry I don't understand it shows (field) IRepository<PersonalInformation> HomeControoller.personRepository. I also create in constructor of HomeContoller next:   personRepository   = new MainRepository<PersonalInformation>(); and
            usersRepository = new MainRepository<ApplicationUser>();

Comment: @NetMage I think I know where is mistake. In my MainRepository where I implement method get I use  return db.Set<T>(); where db is ApplicationDbContext , but it is strange because ApplicationDbContext is Identity context and I don't understand why I get error

Comment: You can't join two `IQueryables` from two different contexts. I'm sure the *full* exception message tells you something like that.

Comment: @GertArnold ok , what I should to do with this? How  I can rewrite this LiNQ??

Comment: Just execute the two queries separately and then compose the `PersonalInfoModel`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likely that you are having an error combining queries from two different database contexts. Your custom `PersonalInformation` is probably in a custom DBContext while `Users` is in the `IdentityDBContext`. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902756/asp-net-identity-dbcontext-confusion). You can either:

**Move all of your tables into the same context.**

- Avoids future confusion between these tables
- More efficient if you end up with lots of associations across contexts.
- A more involved solution just to get this one example working.

**Query your tables separately and combine in memory.**

- Less scalable if you have a huge number of users.
- [These operators will cause EF to return the results so you can process in memory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624700/which-linq-statements-force-entity-framework-to-return-from-the-db)

  ```
  var people = personRepository.Get().ToList();
  var users = usersRepository.Get().ToList();
  var infoModels = users.GroupJoin(people,
                                   u => u.Id,
                                   p => p.UserId,
                                   (u, mp) => new { n, ms = ms.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                        .SelectMany(z => z.ms.Select(m => new PersonalInfoModel
                        {
                            Name = m.Name,
                            LastName = m.LastName,
                            Email = z.n.Email
                        }));
  ```